# Blur all other area outside polygon in mapbox-gl

Tags: geojson, mapbox, mapbox-gl

I am trying to create an effect like

[image]

Can view it by adding feature from fiddle in
http://geojson.io/#map=14/46.9597/7.1446

when added the feature in mapbox as geojson layer of mapbox-gl I am getting the following output:

[image]

Fiddle for reference:https://jsfiddle.net/sanketg/24vzxcgo/

I am aware that according to mapbox v2 specification holes may cause problem in rendering pbf.

I have no idea regarding Geojson features.

What am I missing here?Is it that mapbox is not able to render the GeoJson feature neatly?

I am appending world bbox to polygon of GeoJson feature,to create the effect.Any other suggestions for better implementation are also welcome?

Comment: Found a solution for geometry with type polygon we need to add the outer polygon at the start of the geometry array. Stuck at Multipolygon feature type.